# ModelState.AddModelError VS ViewBag.Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, modelstate

Till now I know two ways to display error messages on the view

1. Using `ViewBag`
2. Using `ModelState.AddModelError`

I am curious about which is the recommended way and why?

Many time I have heard that use `ViewBags` for temporary messages and also people advised to avoid use of `ViewBags` at all.

**Using ViewBag**

```
 @if (ViewBag.err != null)
 {
     <label class="text-danger">@ViewBag.err</label>
 }
```

**Using ModelState.AddModelError**

```
 if(result ==1)
 { 
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
 else if(result ==2)
{ 
     ModelState.AddModelError("Ctrlplan", "Control plan already exist"); 
}
else
{
     return View(tblControlPlan);
}
```

**Please let me know if there is more efficient way to display temporary stuff like error messages.**

Comment: Its always best to use ModelState.AddModelError instead of ViewBag, but there are some condition where you may loose the data when ever the new request or page renders happens the data can be lost , so in such cases you have to use viewBag to retain the data.

Comment: @VinuthaN Yes you are right. Sometimes we need to retain the values but not for all the properties. So is it efficient to use ViewBag to store the property values coming from ViewModel and then pass that access that values in POST method  Ex below--- Model.SomeId = ViewBag.SomeId

Comment: yes you are right.